# How can I dynamically update the border if the appropriate index is selected

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-desktop

So I have the following function that creates a list of widgets and saves them in a variable, and then I add the variable as children in a Wrap widget. My problem is that I want to update the border style based on the selected index but it doesn't update it stays static to the first one since the first is selected when the list is generated.

The code:

```dart
int selectedFeature = 0;
List<Widget> features = <Widget>[];

void generateFeatured() {
    var featured = <Widget>[];
    if (movies.length >= 5) {
      for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        featured.add(
          Container(
            height: 150,
            width: 220,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              // color: const Color(0xff39a936),
              border: selectedFeature == i
                  ? Border.all(color: const Color(0xff39a936), width: 2)
                  : Border.all(color: Colors.transparent),
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(
                25,
              ),
              image: DecorationImage(
                fit: BoxFit.cover,
                alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
                image: NetworkImage(
                  movies[i]["cover_image"].toString(),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                left: 20,
                right: 20,
                bottom: 15,
                top: 15,
              ),
              child: Align(
                alignment: Alignment.bottomLeft,
                child: Container(
                  padding:
                      const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 4, vertical: 2),
                  child: Text(
                    movies[i]["title"].toString().toUpperCase(),
                    style: const TextStyle(
                      fontFamily: "MADE",
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    ),
                  ),
                ).asGlass(
                  frosted: false,
                  clipBorderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(4),
                  tintColor: const Color(0xff41535f),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
    } else {
      for (var i = 0; i < movies.length; i++) {
        featured.add(
          Container(
            height: 150,
            width: 220,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              // color: const Color(0xff39a936),
              border: selectedFeature == i
                  ? Border.all(color: const Color(0xff39a936), width: 2)
                  : Border.all(color: Colors.transparent),
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(
                25,
              ),
              image: DecorationImage(
                fit: BoxFit.cover,
                alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
                image: NetworkImage(
                  movies[i]["cover_image"].toString(),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                left: 20,
                right: 20,
                bottom: 15,
                top: 15,
              ),
              child: Align(
                alignment: Alignment.bottomLeft,
                child: Container(
                  padding:
                      const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 4, vertical: 2),
                  child: Text(
                    movies[i]["title"].toString().toUpperCase(),
                    style: const TextStyle(
                      fontFamily: "MADE",
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    ),
                  ),
                ).asGlass(
                  frosted: false,
                  clipBorderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(4),
                  tintColor: const Color(0xff41535f),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
    }
    setState(() {
      features = featured;
    });
  }
```

The widget

```dart
Wrap(
    alignment: WrapAlignment.start,
    spacing: 15,
    runSpacing: 15,
    children: features,
),
```

The result: wrong image having the border

[image]

thanks in advance

Comment: Where do you set your selectedFeature variable?

Comment: I have a timer that updates every 10 seconds

Comment: "[...] and saves them in a variable" that's your problem - instead you should create a brand new list on every update

Comment: ok but won't this be cpu/gpu heavy?

Comment: I want to see the part where you set your selectedFeature variable and not how often the timer updates :D

Comment: it's the first peace of code

Comment: No, the first line of code is when `selectedFeature` is instantiated. Where is the code that actually changes its value? (Basically, if this code is all we have to go on, then `selectedFeature` is always 0 and that's why the highlighted cell never changes.)

Comment: Oh yeah sorry here is the code
```flutter
void changeFeature() {
    if (selectedFeature == features.length - 1) {
      setState(() {
        selectedFeature = 0;
      });
    } else {
      setState(() {
        selectedFeature++;
      });
    }
  }
```